# ASP.NET MVC Database not being created/uploaded System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-connection, asp.net-identity, file-not-found, win32exception

**Background**
I have just created an MVC website (as an application) using *Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web* from the default MVC template using the "Individual user accounts" option. I have created views to fit and added two fields ("Username" and "Birthdate") to the accounts model (using the tutorials by Microsoft). *Note: Everything works fine when running on localhost from visual studio.*

**The Problem**
When I upload the site to [my server](http://www.spiderhouse.org), I get a file not found error (I think it is the accounts database that is not being found). When I upload it (*I am doing this via the file system method*), there is nothing in the AppData folder but there isn't in VS either, it's in the server explorer. If I try to do anything with the accounts on the live server (eg. register a user), I get the following stack trace.

**The Stack Trace**
[image: The Stack Trace]
Note: You can see this for yourself at [spiderhouse.org](http://www.spiderhouse.org) if you register a user; I have left the full error details available and in it's current state (at the time of writing) no info will be saved.

**The Identity Models**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Spiderhouse.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
        public override string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**The Account Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Owin;
using Spiderhouse.Models;

    namespace Spiderhouse.Controllers
    {
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, BirthDate = model.BirthDate };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ConfirmEmail
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
        {
            if (userId == null || code == null) 
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return View("ConfirmEmail");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ForgotPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user either does not exist or is not confirmed.");
                    return View();
                }

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);       
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
                // return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ForgotPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ForgotPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPassword
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string code)
        {
            if (code == null) 
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "No user found.");
                    return View();
                }
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                    return View();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ResetPasswordConfirmation
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Disassociate(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
        {
            ManageMessageId? message = null;
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
            }
            else
            {
                message = ManageMessageId.Error;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage
        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.Error ? "An error has occurred."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
        {
            bool hasPassword = HasPassword();
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasPassword;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasPassword)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), model.NewPassword);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddErrors(result);
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LinkLogin
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Account"), User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/LinkLoginCallback
        public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(XsrfKey, User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
            }
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), loginInfo.Login);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
                var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (info == null)
                {
                    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
                }
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                        // Send an email with this link
                        // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                        // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                        // SendEmail(user.Email, callbackUrl, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link");

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveAccountList()
        {
            var linkedAccounts = UserManager.GetLogins(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = HasPassword() || linkedAccounts.Count > 1;
            return (ActionResult)PartialView("_RemoveAccountPartial", linkedAccounts);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && UserManager != null)
            {
                UserManager.Dispose();
                UserManager = null;
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Helpers
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        private const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";

        private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            }
        }

        private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
        }

        private void AddErrors(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
            }
        }

        private bool HasPassword()
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user.PasswordHash != null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void SendEmail(string email, string callbackUrl, string subject, string message)
        {
            // For information on sending mail, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
            Error
        }

        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        private class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
        {
            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri) : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
            {
            }

            public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
            {
                LoginProvider = provider;
                RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                UserId = userId;
            }

            public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
            public string UserId { get; set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
                }
                context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**The Connection Strings**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Spiderhouse-20141120093225.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Spiderhouse-20141120093225;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

This first line of the exception you mentioned i would get is saying that you don't have SQL express installed on the prod server.

`SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)`

Obviously you will need to have that installed in order for your app to work on the server with the .mdf file that you put out. I'm assuming that when you say you "see nothing in the App_Data folder but you do in the server explorer" you are looking through the Visual Studio Solution Explorer into the App_Data folder, correct? If this is true, I also didn't see anything there, but physically going to the directory in file explorer showed the .mdf and .ldf files that the mvc site created. If you do have SQL Express installed on the server, maybe you forgot to put these files in the correct location on the web server.

In my project I opted to use a remote installation of SQL Server full, in which case I needed to change where the connection string was pointing, but because you included that in the information on your post I think you know that.

Comment: I see the `.mdf` file in the project folder (local) but not in the local publish folder (which gets uploaded to the server). With regards to connection strings, I'm using the default one. I'm not sure whether I should be, I'm just aware they're relevant. As far as the installation of SQL Express is concerned, I'm going to check that now and I'll comment when I know.

Comment: Well, I'm using e-hosting and I don't seem to be able to see any reference to SQL Server Express so I've emailed them about it.

Comment: when you say you're using e-hosting does that mean you do not have access to the iis manager interface?

Comment: All right, SQL Server Express is installed and the appropriate feature is enabled.

Comment: you may need to create an App_Data folder under the site file system and put the .mdf file in there. See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737373/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-4-application-using-localdb-to-local-iis-on-windows-7)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I did exactly what I should have, but I have copied the App_Data directory into the live root directory (the same place as where the Views and Content directories are) and I'm still getting an error. Maybe I misinterpreted the instructions though.

Comment: I'm guessing your issue is either your project doesn't know where the new App_Data folder is or the IIS user isn't configured to run localDB. Take a look at [this](http://goo.gl/a1gc1v) or [this](http://goo.gl/swqXS6) for remapping the `|DataDirectory|` value found in your connection string. [This other post](http://goo.gl/Rxkm4e) talks about how to make changed to the config for the iis user.