# Error: an error occurred while processing your request in MVC after put on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I publish my ASP.NET project to a server, and than client go to my site, several client fine to access my site but several client get error

> Error: an error occurred while processing your request

but I checked - my code is fine. What can I do?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: please try this will help   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737373/how-to-deploy-asp-net-mvc-4-application-using-localdb-to-local-iis-on-windows-7)   or  Open IIS Manager and click on Application Pools.  Make sure the Application Pool your MVC app is running under is set to .NET CLR version is 4 and the pipeline mode is Integrated.

Comment: That's just a generic error message which tells you almost nothing helpful on its own. There could be lots of causes. Start by checking your server's Event Viewer and IIS logs for signs of exceptions or other problems, to help you diagnose the underlying issue